# How do I find the character count of each item in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, where-clause

I'm writing a function that prints string values from a dictionary that have a character count over 8. Below is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to formulate my where condition so that it looks at the number of characters in each string value in the array.

```
var stateCodes = ["NJ": "New Jersey", "CO": "Colorado", "WI": "Wisconsin", "OH": "Ohio"]

func printLongState (_ dictionary: [String: String]) -> (Array<Any>) {
let fullStateNames = Array(stateCodes.values)

for _ in fullStateNames where fullStateNames.count > 8 {
    print(fullStateNames)
    return fullStateNames
}

return fullStateNames
}

printLongState(stateCodes)
```

Comment: Start by removing the `return` statement from inside the loop.

Comment: I cannot see any good reason to return an array of `Any`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go with for loop then you can make it like this way.

```
func printLongState (_ dictionary: [String: String]) -> (Array<Any>) {
    var fullStateNames = [String]()
    for (_, value) in dictionary where value.characters.count > 8 {
        fullStateNames.append(value)
    }
    return fullStateNames
}
```

But this is not Swifty way in Swift what you can do is you can use `flatMap` with your `Dictionary` to make array of `string` or use `dictionary.values.filter`

**Using flatMap with dictionary**

```
func printLongState (_ dictionary: [String: String]) -> (Array<Any>) {  
    return dictionary.flatMap { $1.characters.count > 8 ? $1 : nil }
}
// Call it like this way.
var stateCodes = ["NJ": "New Jersey", "CO": "Colorado", "WI": "Wisconsin", "OH": "Ohio"] 
print(printLongState(stateCodes)) //["Wisconsin", "New Jersey"]
```

**Using filter on `dictionary.values`**

```
func printLongState (_ dictionary: [String: String]) -> (Array<Any>) {  
    return dictionary.values.filter { $0.characters.count > 8 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `filter` your result instead of using a `for-loop`:

**If you want to return a dictionary use the following:**

```
func printLongState (_ dictionary: [String: String]) -> (Array<Any>) {
    let overEightChars = stateCodes.filter({ $0.value.characters.count > 8 })
    return overEightChars
}
```

**If you want to return an array of Strings use the following:**

```
func printLongState (_ dictionary: [String: String]) -> (Array<Any>) {
    return dictionary.values.filter { $0.characters.count > 8 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `filter` together with `characters.count` like this:

```
var states = ["NJ": "New Jersey", "CO": "Colorado", "WI": "Wisconsin", "OH": "Ohio"]

states.filter({ (_, value) -> Bool in
    return value.characters.count > 8
}).map({ (_, value) in
    print(value)
})
```